# Pasar datos de la Vista al Controlador en ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

estoy usando ASP.NET Core desde hace poco y tengo el siguiente problema:

Tengo una vista que muestra un DataTable que he cargado previamente de un Excel. Mediante un form quiero llamar a una función que inserta este DataTable en la base de datos. Si lo hago de esta manera el Datatable al llegar al controlador devuelve null y por lo tanto no se inserta ningun registro.

Este es el código de la vista:

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@using System.Data;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Previsualización";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/pantallas.css" />



</head>
<body>


    <h2 class="titulo_secundario">PREVISUALIZACIÓN CARGA MASIVA</h2>

    <hr class="solid" />

    @using (Html.BeginForm("CargaMasiva_insert", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div class="tabla_prev_carga">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            <th>@col.ColumnName</th>


                        }
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                            {
                                <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>

                            }
                        </tr>

                    }
                </tbody>



            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="botones">
            <input type="submit" class="boton_aceptar" value="Aceptar">


        </div>
    }








</body>

</html>
```

Este el de la función del controlador:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult CargaMasiva_insert(DataTable dt)
        {
              // Aquí el dt devuelve siempre null
              return View();

        }
```

¿Habría alguna forma de pasarle este Datatable al controlador? También lo he intentado creando un Modelo y pasando el DataTable como atributo del Modelo, pero sigue devolviendome null

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Si los datos del DataTable ya están en la aplicación por qué no los insertas de una vez en la base de datos? Con relación a tu pregunta, el form solo envía elementos de tipo input y que tengan la propiedad name.

Comment: Porque necesito que pasen primero por una vista de previsualización para que el usuario pueda verlos antes de insertar en base de datos. Esta vista tiene que contener un botón que será el que llame al insert.

Comment: Y el usuario puede modificar esos datos?

Comment: No, no, solo es de lectura.

Comment: Entonces sugiero lo anterior, insertarlos desde la aplicación, te ahorras tiempo haciéndolo así. Se le muestran los datos al usuario  y cuando el usuario confirma se insertan los datos que están en la aplicación. Otra opción que tienes es pedir al DataTable los datos y enviarlos como un json a la aplicación.

Comment: Claro preferiria insertarlos desde la aplicación pero no veo la forma de hacer eso desde el botón de esta vista.

Comment: Ya tienes el código para leer el Excel, al presionar el botón de la vista puedes usar el mismo proceso, leer el Excel e insertarlo en la bd.

Comment: Claro, pero entonces tendría que leer el mismo excel dos veces, no?

Comment: Sí. Siempre hay que hacer un proceso, como te decía ,o lees el Excel usando el código que ya tienes, o extraes los datos de la tabla como json. El primer proceso te ahorra tiempo porque ya lo tienes, pero si quieres intentar el segundo te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Intentaré el segundo entonces a ver si puedo evitar tener que leer el excel dos veces. Gracias por tu tiempo!